# How to get data from external website into a web API in .NET core?

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I am learning to make a web api with .NET core and I followed this documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I have made a new fresh project to start with and this is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace FortniteAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{nickname}";
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

I am using data from this website for my web API https://www.fortnitetracker.com/

The API link requires two parameters and that is platform and nickname. I used my own information but when I start the app I don't see the data.

I also have a header key to use it and this is shown in the documentation.

**To use the API key you need to pass it along as a header with your requests.**

I don't really understand this sentence.

Also I am programming in Ionic 3 and I used this api link with the HTTP get but it didn't work because of CORS. That's why I use a .NET core application to talk with the client.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

```
[HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("APIKEY", header);
            var data = http.GetAsync(url).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return data;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix it thanks for the support!

```
 [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(schemename, header);
            var data = http.GetAsync(url).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return data;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Please Put this Code in your Method And Let me know if you need anything more.

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
var data =  http.PostAsync("Your Url", new StringContent("Data", Encoding.UTF32, "text/xml")).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

//for calling get

var data2=http.GetAsync("").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Please Pass Values in headers using httpClient

Comment: Hi Lavit, thanks for you time! Look at my update and I get this error in my browser 

{"message":"No API key found in request"}

Comment: Yes I can accept the answer tomorrow thanks for your time!

Comment: No problem once you get time  Accept the Answer @Fearcoder